# Is it possible to install wrappers for scripts not available in the package distribution in a local texmf?

Tags: miktex, scripts, perl, texmf-local

Is it possible to install  wrappers for scripts not available in the package distribution in a local texmf ?

I would like to be able to add some perl scripts (not present in the MiKTeX distribution) in different directories of a **local texmf**  without to add a bunch of directories to the PATH of Windows. So I wonder if it is possible to do the same as MiKTeX do for the mains texmf

If I understood well, there are small **.exe** files in the bin of MiKTeX which are **wrappers** for  executing the scripts, and the wrappers look in **scripts.ini** to know the location of the script in texmf. For instance **runperl.exe** in `texmf\miktex\bin\x64` will be executed if a perl script is called by a package, it will find the location ot the script with the name in `script.ini` and execute it ??

Can we use the command `initexmf` in the following manner ?

```
initexmf --mklinks = scripts --admin texmf_local/scripts/myscript.pl
```

Does it add **myscript.pl** in **script.ini** ? and does that make **myscript.pl** a link to **runperl.exe** ?

In any case there is only need for the system to know where are the wrappers and then there is only ONE path to add to the PATH of Windows (the path to the bin of MiKTeX)

I'm not quite sure of what I'm saying. Actually I'm almost sure that I'm confused about that topic. Would you be so kind as to correct me if I am wrong.

And by the way, I suppose there is a **perl interpreter** in MiKTeX somewhere. But where exactly ? This is *not* runperl.exe I believe. Or is it mandatory to install a perl interpreter outside, in case we need the perl scripts of MiKTeK ?

Comment: The only drivers I know of are the PDF, bibliography and FPU drivers.

Comment: There is no perl in miktex you must install it. And no you can't add wrappers yourself. There must be registered in the scripts.ini, this is a security measure.

Comment: But with initexmf, can I not register the script in scripts.ini ?